# Canonical path without resolve symbol link

Tags: symlink

I have a symlink file like this,

```shell
cd /tmp
ln -s /bin/ls /test
```

Now I would like to resolve `../test` to `/test`, but the `readlink` command also resolves the symbol link for me, e.g

```shellsession
$ readlink -f ../test
../test -> /bin/ls
```

Is there any command that would output `/test` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`realpath` from GNU coreutils seems to work for me with the `-s` option:

```shellsession
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ ln -s /bin/ls ../linktest
$ realpath -s ../linktest 
/tmp/linktest
```

From the [GNU coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#realpath-invocation): The `-s` option is:

> `-s`, `--strip`, `--no-symlinks`
>
> Do not resolve symbolic links. (...)

Comment: @AsukaMinato, the backticks do mark a code block the same as the indentation does, so better remove the indentation when swithing to backticks to avoid the actual data from being shown unnecessarily indented. (I didn't even notice that from the review, blah.)